# User singleton and nsuserdefault at init

Tags: ios, swift, save, singleton, nsuserdefaults

I actually have an user singleton object that is filled with the user data ( name, picture, etc .. )

That's not sensitive data, so I store those in session

When I quit the app and relaunch, the singleton init is like that

```
class var sharedInstance: User {
    struct Singleton {
        static var instance = User( firstName: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstName") as? String,
                                    lastName: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("lastName") as? String,
                                    email: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("email") as? String,
                                    profilPicture: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("profilPicture") == nil ?
                                        nil : UIImage(data: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("profilPicture") as NSData))
    }

    return Singleton.instance
}
```

So I was wondering if it exist any tidy solution like that ? 
Or perhaps what I did is a good idea ?

Comment: I'd probably clean it up a little, by removing some of the repeated subexpressions (eg., `let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()`), and putting all of it in a dictionary that got stored in `NSUserDefaults` or implementing `NSCoding` for User and storing that, but yeah, it's a reasonable approach.

Comment: let defaults ? But where will you create it ? Because properties access are not possible with the static var ( and not good for my model ^^).

Also, it's possible to create defaults as a global var. That's what you thought about ?

Comment: Well, I'd recommend not making it a singleton, really not much to gain there, just make it a property on your `AppDelegate` and pass it around (or interested parties can get it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can clean it up a little by using the block initialization syntax to remove some duplicate subexpressions and lookups:

```
class var sharedInstance: User {
    struct Singleton {
        static var instance : User = {
            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            let imageData = defaults.objectForKey("profilPicture") as? NSData

            let user =  User(
                firstName: defaults.objectForKey("firstName") as? String,
                lastName: defaults.objectForKey("lastName") as? String,
                email: defaults.objectForKey("email") as? String,
                profilPicture: imageData != nil ? UIImage(data: imageData!) : nil
            )
            return user
        }()
    }

    return Singleton.instance
}
```

As for storing this info in `NSUserDefaults`, that's the kind of thing it's intended for. so yeah, it's a reasonable approach.  Depending on how many keys you're storing there, it can be useful to cluster things by putting them into dictionaries, so instead of having 4 keys to store a user, create a dictionary with 4 keys in it, and store/load that from NSUserDefaults.  But that's just a way of grouping the information and minimizing key conflicts.